# Can you run a t-test with regression betas/coefficients from the output of separate models?

Tags: r, regression, multiple-regression, t-test, regression-coefficients

In layman terms, if all covariates included in the individual models were the same, would it be fair to run a t-test comparing the coefficients for a variable of interest, e.g., age, where I want to compare if the effect of age is larger for brain regions in Network A vs. B, C, etc. and they were all investigated as separate models but similarly constructed.

Comment: Why can't you fit a model to all data, which includes a grouping variable and its interactions?

Comment: That isn't always a great option, particularly if the data does not support it.

Comment: I don’t think the result will be very likely to be reliable if you do not include the other dataset raw data in the analysis.  If you need separate models for the old and new data, Bayesian modeling makes it easy to jointly model the two study’s data, propagating all the uncertainties.

Comment: I realize I misread your question and saw that you are running t-tests on the coefficients in your regression. In that case my previous comment is irrelevant.

Answer (score 9):

**Yes.**

For a regression of $y$ onto $x_1$ producing $\widehat{\beta}_1$ as an estimate of the effect on $y$ of a 1-unit increase in $x_1$, and another regression of $y$ onto $x_2$ producing $\widehat{\beta}_2$ as an estimate of the effect on $y$ of a 1-unit increase in $x_2$:

**Null hypothesis:**
$\text{H}_0\text{: }\beta_1 - \beta_2 = 0\text{, with H}_{\text{A}}\text{: }\beta_1-\beta_2\ne0$

**Test statistic:**
If $n_1=n_2$, then the test statistic is:

$t = \frac{\widehat{\beta}_1 - \widehat{\beta}_2}{s_{\widehat{\beta}_1 - \widehat{\beta}_2}}\text{, where }s_{\widehat{\beta}_1 - \widehat{\beta}_2} = \sqrt{s^{2}_{\widehat{\beta}_1}+s^2_{\widehat{\beta}_2}}\text{, and }\nu = n_1 + n_2 - 4$.

However, if $n_1\ne n_2$, then the test statistic becomes:

$t = \frac{\widehat{\beta}_1 - \widehat{\beta}_2}{s_{\widehat{\beta}_1 - \widehat{\beta}_2}}\text{, where }s_{\widehat{\beta}_1 - \widehat{\beta}_2} =  \sqrt{\frac{\frac{(n_1 - 2)s^{2}_{y|x_1} + (n_2 - 2)s^{2}_{y|x_2}}{n_1 + n_2 - 4}}{(n_1-1)s^{2}_{x_1}} + \frac{\frac{(n_1 - 2)s^{2}_{y|x_1} + (n_2 - 2)s^{2}_{y|x_2}}{n_1 + n_2 - 4}}{(n_2 - 1)s^{2}_{x_2}}}$

$\text{and where } s_{y|x} = \sqrt{\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}\varepsilon_{i}^{2}}{n-2}} = \sqrt{\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}(y_i - \widehat{y}_{i})^{2}}{n-2}} = \sqrt{\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left[y_i - (\widehat{\alpha} + \widehat{\beta}x_{i})\right]^2}{n-2}}$

(These must be calculated for each sample to produce $s^2_{y|x_1}$ and $s^2_{y|x_2}$.)

***p* value:**
The *p* value for a two-sided test for difference is then:

$p = P(|T_{\nu}|\ge |t|) = 2 \times P(T_{\nu}\ge |t|)$

**Rejection decision:**
As per usual reject $\text{H}_0$ if $p \le \alpha$, and fail to reject $\text{H}_{0}$ if $p > \alpha$.

**Conclusion:**
Your substantive conclusions are then whether you found evidence (i.e. because you rejected $\text{H}_0$), or failed to find evidence (i.e. because you failed to reject $\text{H}_0$) that $\widehat{\beta}_1- \widehat{\beta}_2 \ne 0$ at the $\alpha$ level of significance.

**Reference**

Zar, J. H. (2014) Chapter 18 "Comparing Simple Linear Regression Equations" in [*Biostatistical Analysis: Pearson New International Edition*](https://www.pearson.com/en-gb/subject-catalog/p/biostatistical-analysis-pearson-new-international-edition/P200000005805). Pearson, Harlow, UK. pp 387–403.