Testing difference between regression coefficients for different greoups
I am aware that this questions was addressed several times in this site and that there are certain papers discussing this issue for instance 1, 2.

USING THE CORRECT STATISTICAL TEST FOR THE EQUALITY OF REGRESSION COEFFICIENTS by RAYMOND PATERNOSTER, ROBERT BRAME, PAUL MAZEROLLE, ALEX PIQUERO
Statistical Methods for Comparing Regression Coefficients Between Models

Still the explanations provide don't present a complete mathematical justification and I was hoping some of you may help me out.
Say that we have two groups 1 and 2.
We run the following regression for both groups respectively:
\begin{align}
y=\alpha+\beta_1 x\\
y=\gamma + \beta_2 x
\end{align}
Then I would like to test if $\beta_1=\beta_2$. I am aware that one approach would be to use SUR, or to use a Z test as proposed in the first paper above, i.e.
\begin{align}
Z=\frac{\beta_1-\beta_2}{\sqrt{SE(\beta_1)^2+SE(\beta_2)^2}}
\end{align}
My concern is that we are using estimated standard errors, thus the distribution of the statistic is not going to be Gaussian.
If I can show that the denominator is a square root of a scaled Chi-squared then I can use a T distribution.
I have not been able to derive the actual distribution for this statistic, so I was wondering if this is known.

You are probably looking for the Welch-test which here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welch%27s_t-test explained for the difference of two sample means. It must be similar for two regression coefficients.

Btw, imho the first paper you refer to is a bit naive! It does NOT mention that their formula (3) is meant for situations in which the two within-group variances are assumed to be equal. If that assumptions is true, researcher could better use formula (3) because it would give more power than formula (4), which is meant for different within group variances. To conclude that researchers should always use formula (4) is oversimplifying things.

I indeed tried rewriting the test as a Welch t test but doing so for regression coefficients it's not trivial as far as I'm concerned

Do you use the same $y$ observations for fitting both models or not?

@whuber now I notice that my notation is not the best indeed. I have two sets of data both containing the dependent and independent variables. I run the regression on both separate sets and I want to see if the coefficient is equal in both sets. In particular both sets have different number of observations. I've seen a formula for the t statistic in the answer of this question https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/630630/can-you-run-a-t-test-with-regression-betas-coefficients-from-the-output-of-separ/630683?noredirect=1#comment1216335_630683 although no proof is provided

This is a standard t-test (based on two estimated means and two SDs estimated from each mean), so no additional proof is required: pick which version you think is most appropriate.
